# What can I read about /dev/graphics/fb0 is null for android, test evnironment in 4.0 and 4.3 plantform

Tags: android

I can't find anything to read about `/dev/graphics/fb0,` below is my code .I already  exec "`chmod 777  /dev/graphics/fb0"` before reading fb0; My test environment is Android 4.0 ,4.3 and 4.4.

Below is my code:

```
public static synchronized Bitmap getScreenShotBitmap() {  
    FileInputStream buf = null;  

    try {  
        fbFile = new File(FB0FILE1);  
        buf = new FileInputStream(fbFile);  
        dStream=new DataInputStream(buf);  
        dStream.readFully(piex);   //Java  NULLPOINTException
        dStream.close();  

          for(int i=0;i<piex.length;i+=2)  
            {  
              colors[i/2]= (int)0xff000000 +  
                        (int) (((piex[i+1]) << (16))&0x00f80000)+  
                        (int) (((piex[i+1]) << 13)&0x0000e000)+  
                        (int) (((piex[i]) << 5)&0x00001A00)+  
                        (int) (((piex[i]) << 3)&0x000000f8);  
            }  

  return Bitmap.createBitmap(colors, screenWidth,screenHeight,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);  

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
        LogUtil.e(TAG, "FileNotFoundException error",e);  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        LogUtil.e(TAG, "IOException error",e);  
    }catch (Exception e) {  
        LogUtil.e(TAG, "Exception error",e);  
    }    
    finally {  
        if(buf!=null){  
            try {  
                buf.close();  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    return null;  
}
```

Now this is the[image]  exception:

Comment: please add code instead of images.

Comment: I already added  key code ,can you pls help me ,thx